# Coding standards for developing iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am newbie in iPhone development.
I want to start a project and want to know coding standards of objective-C like naming, casting etc.
Thanks

Comment: People write *whole books* on coding standards.  This is way too big a question to fit here.

Comment: [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) is **Official Coding Guidelines from Apple**, may help you

Comment: thank you @RDC Its ben long time I have asked this question, now I have make mine own standards and completed many applications with good coding standards

Comment: @Will really great to hear that, I just came here accidentally and thought, no one shared any info related to the question, so shared link, btw I appreciate if you can please share the coding standards you collected,if you don't mind, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with reading Apple documentation on the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). It contains a wealth of howtos, tutorials and technical stuff.

Comment: Namely, try the iOS Starting Point doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007853

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting fresh and want to learn the basics, Ray Wenderlich has some great guides out there, especially for people new to the language. You could try starting with [this tutorial he has created](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1). Enjoy the ride :)

Answer (score 1):

Google also has an Objective-C style guide [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)

Some of its rules might be questionable, but it is nicely succinct and covers most of the key language constructs.